# How to use a variable with dynamic field names for ON DUPLICATE KEY in a trigger (MariaDB/MySQL)

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I have hundreds of databases with some structurally identical (but over time changing) tables. Data of a certain table (from all DBS) should be copied into one central table ('ex_objects') in a central database ('db_central'; there are no pk conflicts). I've used a trigger in each DB for this purpose. But since the table structure is changing almost on a daily basis, it's a pain to update the fields in the ON DUPLICATE KEY part of the trigger's query. And someone could forget to modify the trigger after modifying the table structure. So I came across a possible solution to build that particular part of the query dynamically. This actually works on a script (PHP) basis, but I don't get the trigger done. I don't see what I am missing here.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE VAL_FIELDS TEXT;
    SET VAL_FIELDS = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,"=values(", COLUMN_NAME,")") SEPARATOR ", ") FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_central' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ex_objects');
--  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,"=values(", COLUMN_NAME,")") SEPARATOR ", ") INTO VAL_FIELDS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_central' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ex_objects';
--  SELECT @VAL_FIELDS := GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,"=values(", COLUMN_NAME,")") SEPARATOR ", ") INTO VAL_FIELDS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_central' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ex_objects';

    IF NEW.online = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO db_central.ex_objects 
            SELECT * FROM ex_objects WHERE id = NEW.id AND client_id = NEW.client_id AND NEW.online = 1 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VAL_FIELDS;
    END IF;
END
```

I get the error that there's something wrong at `; END IF; END`. Well, that means for me, that either the `VAL_FIELDS` variable after `KEY UPDATE` isn't recognized at all or the parser expects at least one equation (something like `VAL_FIELDS = whatever`). But in this case, it wouldn't solve my underlying problem at all.

The `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,"=v ... FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.C ...` Query works well and results in something similar to `id=values(id), xfield=values(xfield), yfield=values(yfield)` (but with a few hundred fields, since the table is actually pretty huge).

**The full error**: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';
    END IF;
END' at line 10

Answer (score 0):

You must build the SQL using `CONCAT`, etc, then `prepare` and `execute` it.  There is no 'interpolation'.

Since it is a `TRIGGER`, that won't work.

However, since a `TRIGGER` applies to a particular table, you may as well simply spell out the query, not construct it.  You have most of what it takes to manually get the query generated for you (`SELECT ... I_S ...`).  Add some more columns for `OLD.col` to fill out the thing; viola, you have the query that you need.

Comment: That would be nice if it worked (tried it), but triggers don't support dynamic queries, unfortunately.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that -- see my modification.